# Can I run two non-thunderbolt displays from a thunderbolt RAID device?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, raid

It seems like this question has been asked a million times, but after a few hours of reading similar questions, I have not been able to find a clear answer.

I have a mid-2012 Macbook Air running OS X 10.9. I want to run dual 24" 1920x1200 monitors *and* the built-in 11" screen.

Can I use a thunderbolt RAID device (i.e. Promise Pegasus R4 or anything else with two thunderbolt ports out) to drive two monitors?

Will this work:

MBA -> RAID -> 2x miniDP to DVI adaptors -> 2x 24" screens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not with the Promise Pegasus R4 has only two Thunderbolt ports. One you will need to connect to the MBA and then other to your miniDP adapter. You would need a Thunderbolt dock that has another Thunderbolt port or another video interface like HDMI, etc.

Something like this: http://www.caldigit.com/thunderboltstation/,etc

Comment: Wow. That makes so much sense! I assumed there was a third TB "in" port for some reason.

Comment: Make sure you read the FAQ page for the CalDigit product (http://www.caldigit.com/thunderboltstation/faq.asp). It states "the Thunderbolt Station can support two monitors *if one of them is an Apple Thunderbolt Display*". It doesn't support two non Thunderbolt monitors.